# Regression in subpopulations using svyglm function in the R survey package

Tags: r, subset, survey

I would like to use the `svyglm` function from the `survey` package to run stratified regression models/regression models on subset of my population.

Suppose `x` is my predictor, `y` is my outcome, and `z` is a third (factor) variable. I would like to see individual relationships between `x` and `y` for different levels of `z`.

The documentation for this package says that "The correct standard error estimate for a subpopulation that isn’t a stratum is not just obtained by pretending that the sub population was a designed survey of its own. However, the subset function and `[` method for survey design objects handle all these details automagically, so you can ignore this problem."

There is a subset argument in the svyglm function. My question is - **do you specify the subpopulation in the subset argument of the design function, in the svyglm function, or both?**

Comment: maybe see examples at http://asdfree.com/european-social-survey-ess.html   create the subset object (like `sub_ess_design`) then use that in your `svyglm()` call in place of `ess_design`

Answer (score 0):

Either one, but not both.

The code inside `svyglm` looks like

```
   subset <- substitute(subset)
    subset <- eval(subset, model.frame(design), parent.frame())
    if (!is.null(subset)) 
        design <- design[subset, ]
```

The first two lines are handling where to look up the subset, and then it just gets used to `[` the design.